# How to restrict angular.module('myApp', [ 'ngGrid', 'ui.bootstrap', 'kendo.directives' ]);?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have two angular js files in

**myjs1.js** and i have included

```
angular.module('myApp', [ 'ngGrid', 'ui.bootstrap', 'kendo.directives' ]);
```

**myjs2.js** i have also included

```
angular.module('myApp', [ 'ngGrid', 'ui.bootstrap', 'kendo.directives' ]);
```

these modules . On my **html** pages i have to include both the js files

**myhtml.html**

```
<script src="../../js/myjs1.js"></script>
<script src="../../js/myjs2.js"></script>
```

but the problem is that in both the js files i have to include `angular.module('myApp', [ 'ngGrid', 'ui.bootstrap', 'kendo.directives' ]);`
due to which **myhtml.html** is throwing error as both the ngGrid module are conflicting.

when i remove `angular.module('myApp', [ 'ngGrid', 'ui.bootstrap', 'kendo.directives' ])`;  from one js i am able to get the output in grid as there is no confliction of modules. 
But i can't remove `angular.module('myApp', [ 'ngGrid', 'ui.bootstrap', 'kendo.directives' ]);` from any of the js files as ngGrid module is required by other html files.

my question is how to restrict the module ngrid not to include in my one html file and got used by other html files.

**Can i control by  `<html ng-app="myApp">` tag used separately for both the html files ??**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create multiple modules with different names and add them as a dependency to your `myApp` module.

For Example:

**module1.js**

```
angular.module('myModule1', [ 'ngGrid', 'ui.bootstrap', 'kendo.directives' ]);
```

**module2.js**

```
angular.module('myModule2', [ 'ngGrid', 'ui.bootstrap', 'kendo.directives' ]);
```

**app.js**

```
angular.module('myApp', [ 'myModule1', 'myModule2' ]);
```

Then in your html file include them in following order:

```
<script src="../../js/module1.js"></script>
<script src="../../js/module2.js"></script>
<script src="../../js/app.js"></script>
```